# Spinner UI example in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Here is my UI xml file example which has 3 Spinners Currently its showing in 3 different rows.
But I wanted it in single row (1 row 3 column).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinHour"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="124dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinMin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinHour" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinRepeat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinMin" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinRepeat"
        android:text="Submit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean `Spinners`?

Comment: create linear layout with horizontal orieantation... and put 3 spinners in there...

Comment: putting 4 widgets in a single column in android is not good as for smaller devices their width would be preety small to be usable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinHour"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinMin"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinRepeat"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using this UI in a Fragment/Tab, Problem here is spinners are colliding with Tabs text. How to avoid this thing ?

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS CODE..................

YOU CAN USE **`LinearLayout`** to put your spinner in same row..
use **`android:layout_weight`** property for view your spinner same size..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinHour"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinMin"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinRepeat"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

     <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linear_spinner"
            android:text="Submit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```